# Prove $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^a=\frac{1}{q}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This was a part of a larger proof and might be a very simple question but I don't seem to get it.

Assuming $p+q=1$, $p>q$, $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)>0$ and $a>0$, we get 
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^a=\frac{1}{q}$$.

I don't know how we got there and I have tried to open the brackets as follows
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^a=\frac{p^a}{q^a}=\frac{(1-q)^a}{q^a}=\frac{q^a-2aq+a}{q^a}$$
but I get nowhere.

Comment: If $a$ is any number then this isn't true. Try $p=\frac{1}{3}$ and $q=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: There is information missing to conclude what is written.

Comment: Part of a larger proof? What are you trying to prove? And what have you done prior to this step?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Sorry, I forgot to add that a is positive. I edited it now in!

Comment: It is still a wrong question . Do you want to say 'there exists $a>0$ 'or 'for all $a >0$?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $q>0$ (and real $a$), one would need the following value of $a$ in order for the equality to hold.

\begin{align}
\frac{{(1-q)}^a} {q^a} = \frac 1q
&\iff
{(1-q)}^a =q^{a-1}
\\&\iff
a\log(1-q) = (a-1)\log(q)
\\&\iff
a\big(\log(1-q) - \log(q)\big) = -\log(q)
\\&\iff
a = \frac{-\log(q)}{\log(1-q) - \log(q)} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{\log(1-q)}{\log(q)}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Surely some additional information is required on $a$. Otherwise, the result is just false in general.

Comment: I forgot to add that a has to be positive. Sorry, I added that in now!

Comment: @Joe It is not enough... The equality would only hold for a specific value of $a$.